# CefSharp ist not performing the button action to start a local exe

Tags: wpf, cefsharp

I want to show a local html with a button which should call a custom protocol to open a local app - by using a registry setting in 'HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT' (see [here](https://support.shotgunsoftware.com/hc/en-us/articles/219031308-Launching-applications-using-custom-browser-protocols)). The html looks like

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
...
<body>
    <input type="button" onclick="location.href='xyz:OpenApp?id=123';" value="Open App" />
</body>
</html>
```

This works from within Chrome, IE and Edge, and no matter if I load the html as file directly or start it by calling http://localhost from [tiny web server](https://www.ritlabs.com/en/products/tinyweb/).

**But unfortunately I have no luck when this page is shown either way by CefSharp** (Wpf, Version 79.1.360 on Win10 64Bit, 1909, .NET 4.6.1) - instead (after clicking the button ) the html page flips to a blank page and the action is not performed.

I am loading the html as follows:

```
Browser.Address = @"http://localhost/"; // or
Browser.Address = @"D:\TestButton.html";
```

I also tried applying CefSettings, e.g. to set LogLevel to Verbose, but the debug.log (at the moment of clicking) contains nothing I would understand:

```
[0505/083914.727:ERROR:paint_controller.cc(548)] PaintController::FinishCycle() completed
[0505/083914.817:INFO:cpu_info.cc(53)] Available number of cores: 4
[0505/083914.841:VERBOSE1:v8_context_snapshot.cc(153)] A context is created from snapshot for main world
[0505/083914.859:VERBOSE1:script_context.cc(117)] Created context:
  extension id:           (none)
  frame:                  00000E926B822498
  URL:                    
  context_type:           WEB_PAGE
  effective extension id: (none)
  effective context type: WEB_PAGE
[0505/083914.859:VERBOSE1:script_context.cc(117)] Created context:
  extension id:           (none)
  frame:                  0000000000000000
  URL:                    
  context_type:           UNSPECIFIED
  effective extension id: (none)
  effective context type: UNSPECIFIED
[0505/083914.859:VERBOSE1:dispatcher.cc(362)] Num tracked contexts: 1
[0505/083914.865:ERROR:paint_controller.cc(548)] PaintController::FinishCycle() completed
[0505/083914.869:VERBOSE1:dispatcher.cc(539)] Num tracked contexts: 0
[0505/083914.870:VERBOSE1:script_context.cc(124)] Destroyed context for extension
  extension id: 
  effective extension id: 
[0505/083914.870:VERBOSE1:script_context.cc(124)] Destroyed context for extension
  extension id: 
  effective extension id:
```

I have no clue which other setting could affect this and I am aware that this problem is maybe related to CEF and not to CefSharp in particular, but I am not able to find this out.

Any idea someone?

Comment: There is no setting, you have to implement http://cefsharp.github.io/api/79.1.x/html/M_CefSharp_IResourceRequestHandler_OnProtocolExecution.htm unfortunately there is a problem with this method currently https://bitbucket.org/chromiumembedded/cef/issues/2715/onprotocolexecution-page-goes-blank-after

Comment: As a workaround you can likely perform a shell execute as suggested in https://bitbucket.org/chromiumembedded/cef/issues/2715/onprotocolexecution-page-goes-blank-after#comment-57191176 the relevant handler they suggested is http://cefsharp.github.io/api/79.1.x/html/M_CefSharp_IRequestHandler_OnBeforeBrowse.htm you can override http://cefsharp.github.io/api/79.1.x/html/M_CefSharp_Handler_RequestHandler_OnBeforeBrowse.htm as http://cefsharp.github.io/api/79.1.x/html/T_CefSharp_Handler_RequestHandler.htm provides a default implementation